# How can I do -- mod power of two quickly just like one does ++ power of two quickly?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am keeping an index counter to what ought to behave like a circular array. I force the size to be a power of two, and thus use `size_t MASK = size_ - 1` in order to replace modulus when traversing like this:

```
index_ = (++index_) & MASK;
```

but the problem is, in my situation, I sometimes realize that I can reuse that index I handed out the next time around here, and so when that happens I have something like this:

```
if (canReuseLastUsedIndex())
    --index_;
```

but then this crashes when the last dished out `index_` was zero because this does not wrap around to `size_` (i.e. `MASK+1`). Is there a bitop way to have this happen? Or something very fast? (i.e. preferably not having to say: `if (index_) --index_; else index_ = size_`)

Comment: Leave such micro-optimizations to your optimizing compiler (e.g. `g++ -O3 -Wall` or `clang++ -O3`). They will do better than you or we can.

Comment: You mean else index_ = size_ -1; ... (--index & MASK) will just work

Comment: There's always `index_ = (index_ + MASK) & MASK;`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: interestingly, `if(index) { return index - 1; } else { return size; }` does not get optimized. It's probably useless, but it does not.

Comment: But such optimizations are strongly depending on the actual context, which optimizing compilers do take into account! You should *measure the execution time* of the generated optimized code, instead of looking at a few lines of generated assembly.

Comment: If you are using a CPU designed in the 21st century (or even late 20th century) it is very likely that `index & MASK` and `index % size` take the same amount of time. If you are using a compiler released in the last 20 years, and if `size` is a constant power of two, it is likely that the two expressions produce the same machine code, too.

Comment: Rob, but if size were decided at runtime, how would this be possible? I can enforce in the constructor that it will be a power of two by rounding up to nearest power of two and then I know I can use the & operator correctly.

Comment: @Robᵩ If `size` is known at compile time, yes. Otherwise, don't expect it. Regarding `index & MASK` vs `index % size`, I have never had the pleasure of working with a CPU where division is not at least ten times slower than multiplication, addition or bit-operations, so if `size` is not known at compile time, but _you_ know it will always be a power of 2, for all that's holy, use the mask.

Comment: @DanielFischer - some quick research ([1](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) and [2](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/248966.pdf)) reveals that I am clearly wrong on the relative speed of AND and DIV on modern processors. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the same thing and bitmask it:

```
index_ = (index_ - 1) & MASK;
```

This works because unsigned underflow is well-defined in C and C++.

Note that this line of code is *undefined behavior*:

```
index_ = (++index_) & MASK;
```

Because you're modifying the variable `index_` more than once between sequence points (in both the preincrement and the assignment).

Comment: FWIW, that's not underflow. That's negative overflow.

Comment: Wait that's undefined behavior? Then what is the right way to do that line?

Comment: @PalaceChan `index = (index+1)&MASK;`

Answer (score 1):

You're already doing it. Simply apply `MASK` the same as you did with addition:

```
index_ = (index_ - 1) & MASK;
```